# LazyInitializationException when using join in CrudRepository

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, lazy-initialization

getting org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session 
when I call ***findByUserEmail(String email)***

The service class *(where I'm calling this function)* is marked as **@Transactional**

**Repository**

```
@Repository
public interface UserImagesRepository extends CrudRepository<User_images, Integer> {
    List<User_images> findByUserEmail(String email);
}
```

**User**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@NamedQuery(name = "User.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM User u")
public class User implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private String email;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
    private Set<User_images> images = new HashSet<User_images>(0);

    //getters and setters
}
```

**User_images**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_images")
public class User_images implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId")
    private User user;

    // getters and setters
}
```

**___UPDATE___**

The `UserImageRepository` has **no** implementation, queries are automatically generated from method name directly. [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html)

I don't want to use eager loading as its bad practice.

Comment: Can you share the implementation of findByUserEmail(String email) method?

Comment: FetchType.Lazy means that fetch when needed , so when you call `findByUserEmail(String email)`,if in this fuction you are fetching some thing which is associated with another table after the service method call it will give the LazyInitailzation exception as session is closed.try replacing with fetch=FetchType.Eager all places , it should work. 1.http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2014/04/orghibernatelazyinitializationException-Could-not-initialize-proxy-no-session-hibernate-java.html 2.http://uaihebert.com/four-solutions-to-the-lazyinitializationexception/

Comment: Is the exception occurring inside the `findByUserEmail` method? Perhaps your stacktrace would help us, or even the actual code in this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you see something like `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session`, it is because of you are trying access a lazy-loading property outside transaction boundary.

In some case it is because you haven't setup transaction manager etc correctly, therefore once you get the entities from the repository, there is already no active Session.

In most case, you are trying to access lazy-loading property outside where you declared transactional.  For example, there may be one Controller calling your Service (Your Service is where the transaction boundary is declared), and in the controller you are doing something like `user.getImages()`.  You should make sure you have already fetched the images before you return from Service. (There are some other ways like "Open Session In View" but that's never my preferred solution).

Such kind of lazy property access may not be explicit, for example, it may be triggered by you are calling `toString()` of `User` because of logging, or you are using a debugger to inspect the content of `User`.

Off topic advise: Make sure you complies to Java's convention in naming.  It should be `UserImage` instead of `User_images`